# grails-2.3.0.M1 fails to start in IntelliJ IDEA 130.754

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have project running on grails 2.2.1 in IntelliJ IDEA 130.754.

After upgrading of grails version to 2.3.0.M1 grails fails to start

Log from IDEA console

```
/home/aram/local/java/bin/java -Dgrails.home=/home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1 -Dbase.dir=/home/aram/projects/grails/app/formx -Dtools.jar=/home/aram/local/java/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar:/home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.0.M1-sources.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/conf/groovy-starter.conf upgradeError: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

I guess problem is with

```
  /home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.0.M1-sources.jar
```

maybe it need to be

```
/home/aram/local/grails-2.3.0.M1/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.0.M1.jar
```

instead.

Any help how to fix issue ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As workaround you can remove all "grails-*-2.3.0.M1-sources.jar" and "grails-*-2.3.0.M1-javadocs.jar" from $GRAILS_HOME/dist

Problem will be fixed in the next EAP.

Comment: Note that this also is broken for the RC1 release as well

Comment: Here's an easy command to delete them, after you've gotten into the `dist` directory: `ls | grep grails-.*-2\.3\.0\.RC1-.*\.jar$ | xargs rm` (for the RC1, this works. Replace RC1 for other releases)

Comment: Also broken with the GA release of Grails 2.3.0.

Comment: little correction: in grails 2.3.11, it would be grails-*javadoc.jar, instead of javadocs.