# Grails GGTS IDE GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died

Tags: macos, exception, grails, ide, spring-tool-suite

I have faced following weird exception on GGTS IDE .

```
    Command terminated with an exception: org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: 
Grails process died (see details for partial output)
    Grails process died
    ------System.out:-----------

    ------System.err:-----------
```

I tried with following releases and still got same issue

- groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.3.0.RELEASE-e3.8.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64-installer.dmg
- groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.3.0.RELEASE-e4.3-macosx-cocoa-x86_64-installer.dmg

Operation System is MAC OS X Version 10.7.5
JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

after first installation I deleted .grails folder and all grails related folders but cant see any side effect about workaround.

I can create project via command line but not mange on GGTS, whenever execute any grails command via GGTS IDE still facing same error message.

Any Feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end , I found a solution about this problem. I was give up to continue after couple of days investigation on GGTS and decided to install Intellij 12 on mac. Installed trial licence for İntellij. I was expecting to avoid this problem. However I faced again an another wierd exception on İntellij. I had started to investigate current problem on intellij forums.

As a result,I found following advice to solve issue on intellij environment. The following instruction also solve my GGTS problem on mac.

[Grails 2.3.0.RC1 and IntelliJ IDEA: "IDEA hook: Grails not found!"](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-0-RC1-and-IntelliJ-IDEA-quot-IDEA-hook-Grails-not-found-quot-td4647657.html)

it was referencing following solution also on stackoverflow.com

[grails-2.3.0.M1 fails to start in IntelliJ IDEA 130.754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919676/grails-2-3-0-m1-fails-to-start-in-intellij-idea-130-754)

> **Solution :**
>   remove all "grails-*-2.3.0.M1-sources.jar" and "grails-*-2.3.0.M1-javadocs.jar" from $GRAILS_HOME/dist

Regards

Answer (score 23):

[This link](http://jolorenz.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/how-to-solve-the-grailsprocessdiedexception-in-grailsgroovy-tool-suite-ggts-3-4-0) suggests a workaround for your error message.

I remember that I encountered this problem firstly with GGTS 3.2.0 and solved it with the following workaround:
In GGTS click

```
Preferences -> Groovy -> Grails -> Launch Grails

and uncheck “Keep external Grails running“.
```

The workaround was suggested by https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3277 and the issue is marked as solved, but obviously it still exists at least in GGTS 3.4.0 and GGTS 3.5.0.M1.

Nevertheless, while using the suggested workaround (uncheck ”Keep external Grails running“) the GrailsProcessDiedException disappeared and the problem was solved.

Regards

Comment: This also solves the same problem in Eclipse Luna and GGTS 3.6.3 plugin