# Unable to run Grails application using Groovy/Grails Tools Suite 3.6.4

Tags: grails, ggts

### Versions:-

> Grails  - 3.1.7, Groovy  - 2.4.6, Java    - 1.8.0, Operating System      - Ubuntu 16.04
>   LTS

I'm able to create an application and run via command line interface (terminal) on ubuntu OS. But when I tried to import the same application (import as grails project) on GGTS the below error message is displayed.

> '/home/shravan/grails/demo' doesn't look like a Grails project

Then I tried to create a new grails project from the tool suite itself and configured the grails installation and when I do so, this error message is displayed.

> Command terminated with an exception:
>   org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException:
>   Grails process died (see details for partial output) Grails process
>   died
>   ------System.out:-----------
>   ------System.err:----------- Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter

I'd like you guys to help me resolve this issue as I'm new to this grails application. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You probably should look into this thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968665/grails-ggts-ide-grailsprocessdiedexception-grails-process-died

Comment: @Mamun I did follow the steps what you have shared in your comment but still I'm getting the same issue. Please let me know if you have any other workaround. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

GGTS does not support Grails 3. Nobody has been maintaining GGTS for over a year, so it doesn't look like it ever will support Grails 3. I recommend switching to IntelliJ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like Donal mentioned, GGTS doesn't support Grails 3 and it is not been maintained. So it's better you use IntelliJ.

The biggest advantage of IntelliJ is that it's very fast and developer friendly and you can use Grails 3 on it's free community version since Grails 3 is based on Gradle.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/