# Grails 3.2.9 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, grails

i just installed `Grails 3.2.9`  here is the output of `grails -version`

```
 Grails Version: 3.2.9
 Groovy Version: 2.4.10
 JVM Version: 1.8.0_131
```

tried to make `New Grails project` from `Eclipse Luna 4.4.2` but this error occurred

```
 Command terminated with an exception: 
org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails 
process died (see details for partial output)
Grails process died
------System.out:-----------

------System.err:-----------
Error: Could not find or load main class 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

and when i tried to run `create-app` from the command line got the below error:

```
     grails> create-app testme --stacktrace
| Warning Unrecognized flag: stacktrace.
| Error Command [create-app] error: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
 java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.handleCommand(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:378)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closur
 e6.doCall(GrailsCli.groovy:469)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closur
 e6.call(GrailsCli.groovy)
 Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Windows\System32\appmgmt\MACH
 INE
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.findAllFilesByName(C
 reateAppCommand.groovy:197)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.handle(CreateAppComm
and.groovy:248)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.handle(CreateAppComm
 and.groovy:341)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.executeCommandWithArgumentValidation(GrailsC


   li.groovy:287)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_execute_closure3.doCall(GrailsCli.groovy:25
    0)
        ... 4 more
    | Error Command [create-app] error: null
    grails>
```

any ideas what caused these errors.

Comment: I have suggestion for you ,If you want to use eclipse then use GGTS , official grails tools suits IDE.Or you can use IntelliJ.

Comment: @Sayem Tried GGTS  same exception also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574925/unable-to-run-grails-application-using-groovy-grails-tools-suite-3-6-4)

Comment: GGTS does not support grails 3 . Use IntelliJ instead.

Comment: @Sayem unfortunately  I don't want to move to another IDE

Answer (score 0):

What causes this error is that Eclipse Luna doesn't support Grails 3.  You can try upgrading to Mars or later (later is preferred), or another IDE like others have suggested, but unfortunately Luna was released in 2014 and is just too old to have support for Grails 3 at this point.

Comment: This may be helpful, though it's a bit old: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/eclipse-mars-grails-3-1-with-gradle-groovy-and-gsp-support/

Comment: nice link and followed the steps on `eclipse oxgen 4.7` but still getting this error `Command terminated with an exception: org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died (see details for partial output)
Grails process died
------System.out:-----------
 
------System.err:-----------
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
`

Comment: Updated the original post