# GGTS (3.4.0) doesn't work with grails 2.3.3 on Mac OS X (10.7.5)

Tags: eclipse, macos, grails, spring-tool-suite, grails-2.3

I can't get GGTS (3.4.0) to work with grails 2.3.3, java 1.7.0_u45 and groovy 2.1. I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5. Everything works fine in Terminal, i.e. I can create projects (create-app), run them (run-app), clean-all, etc. But those commands just just won't work in IDE.

I've already performed fixes mentioned in the posts below, but only error message has changed:

[Grails GGTS IDE GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968665/grails-ggts-ide-grailsprocessdiedexception-grails-process-died)

[grails-2.3.0.M1 fails to start in IntelliJ IDEA 130.754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919676/grails-2-3-0-m1-fails-to-start-in-intellij-idea-130-754)

Any help would be appreciated.

I have JAVA_HOME pointing to the proper jdk like so:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And I have an entry for GRAILS_HOME like so

```
export GRAILS_HOME="/Users/user1/opt/frameworks/grails-2.3.3"
```

When I check my java, groovy and grails versions in Terminal I get:

```
$> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

$> groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.1.3 JVM: 1.7.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

$> grails -version
Grails version: 2.3.3
```

I've also added grails 2.3.3 in the GGTS settings, installed Grails and Groovy 2.1 plugins as well.

I'm getting the following error whenever try to create new grails project or refresh-depencies on an imported one:

```
> ------System.out:-----------  |Loading Grails 2.3.3 |Configuring classpath . |Environment set to development ..................Error  |
> Error executing script Compile:
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils.getPluginSourceFiles(Ljava/lang/String;)[Lorg/springframework/core/io/Resource;
> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
> ------System.err:-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally made it work by using different version of GGTS 3.4.0 (based on eclipse 3.8.2, instead of eclipse 4.3.1). There are probably some issues with latest eclipse on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

It wouldn't work without of unchecking "keep external grails running" option though.